# Publishing on /map topic only once and data output format

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to run nav2_map_server. I am seeing map_server is publishing only once on topic /map even and this is published when I launch the node. I can provide the launch file if necessary.
And the echo on the topic looks something like this.

```
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1647904550
    nanosec: 512909420
  frame_id: map
info:
  map_load_time:
    sec: 1647904550
    nanosec: 512906384
  resolution: 0.019999999552965164
  width: 632
  height: 799
  origin:
    position:
      x: -10.0
      y: -20.24
      z: 0.0
    orientation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
data:
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
```

When I was working with ros1 I use to get data in form of an array/matrix but this is kind of new to me. Is this the right format of an output or is it something that I am missing?
Thanks in advance for the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397829/publishing-on-/map-topic-only-once-and-data-output-format/) by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2022-03-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-03-21**:
As I understand from documentation there: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/main/nav2_map_server and a description there: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/main/nav2_map_server, after map load request you have this map published on `/map` topic once. If you want to publish it more than 1 time, you have to request it again each time. I could be wrong, I am still learning Nav2...

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2022-03-21**:
okay, so do you mean I have to make a service call every time I want the map data. And do you know if the output data is in the correct format?

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-03-22**:
I copied the same link twice, second link should be https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/packages/configuring-map-server.html, I cannot edit it now, sorry. I will check the source code and the format of this message in a moment :)

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-03-22**:
Based on this https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_map_server/include/nav2_map_server/map_server.hpp it should be this format http://docs.ros.org/en/lunar/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html - it seems to match what you got there. You can check it easily with `ros2 node info /your_node_name` too :) I would call this service https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_msgs/srv/LoadMap.srv to get the map.

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2022-03-22**:
Thanks @ljaniec it helped :D.
Data provided on the map topic is in a 1D array with row-major, so I have to convert from 1D to 2D using other methods.
And to get the map data I have to run the map_server which only pub 1 time as you mentioned.
For my other problem, I need to add map_server to my launch file so that my other nodes get the data as soon as map_server launches. There must be another way I can request without launching but will work with this method until I find another solution.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-03-25**:
I think it could be a new question overall, let's solve problems step by step, you can link it there too. I will paste these comments as an answer too, so you can upvote and mark question as solved.

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2022-03-25**:
I think my problem was in understanding if map_server publishes only once- which is true
and the other was [data format](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html#:%7E:text=%23%C2%A0The%C2%A0map%C2%A0data%2C%C2%A0in%C2%A0row%2Dmajor%C2%A0order%2C%C2%A0starting%C2%A0with%C2%A0(0%2C0).) which is in form of a 1D row-major array.
We can mark it as solved. Thanks for help @ljaniec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I understand from documentation there:

- https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/main/nav2_map_server

and a description there:

https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/packages/configuring-map-server.html

after map load request you have this map published on /map topic once. If you want to publish it more than 1 time, you have to request it again each time.

Based on this:
https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_map_server/include/nav2_map_server/map_server.hpp

it should be this format: http://docs.ros.org/en/lunar/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html

It seems to match what you got there. You can check it easily with `ros2 node info /your_node_name` too :)

I would call this service:

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_msgs/srv/LoadMap.srv

(it could be done within the code too normally, not only with launchers)

Copied from the discussion under question.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1